# SqlBulkCopy column mapping not having 'instant effect'?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a `sourceTable` and `targetTable`, which, `targetTable` is all the same but one column less to `sourceTable`, so unless I specify `SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping` before `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer`, the code won't work.

my key code is as this:

```
using (SqlDataReader sd = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()){
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(targetConnString)){
try{ 
       conn.Open();
       using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(targetConnString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
       {
           bc.BulkCopyTimeout = 10800;
           bc.BatchSize = 10000;
           bc.DestinationTableName = targetTable;
           bc.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(PrintPercentCopied);//just print some info
           bc.NotifyAfter = 1000;
           try
           {
                 TryResolveColumnMappingByName(bc, sourceTable, targetTable);
                 bc.WriteToServer(sd);
           }
           catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
           {
                 bc.WriteToServer(sd);                                        
           } 
       }
 }finally { conn.Close(); }
 ......

 private void TryResolveColumnMappingByName(SqlBulkCopy bc, string sourceTable, string targetTable)
 {
     //by whatever logic... and foreach... 
     bc.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(sourceCol, targetCol));  
 }
```

The execution result is wield: inside `try` block, the first attempt of `WriteToServer` get failed and the `ex.Message` saying column mapping is wrong, just same as if I don't try to specify column mapping; then in the `catch` block, nothing more fix has been done, but the code completed with success, both in code and copy result.

so what is happening behind for such behavior?
Both servers are MS SQL server.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and stepping through the code to ensure your mapping is happening as expected?

Comment: @a4194304 Sorry, but I don't understand if it works with column mappings then why are you looking for a solution which does not need mappings?